# Bounds on norm of matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $A = n\times n$ matrix with the real parts of its eigenvalues are contained in $[\alpha, \beta]$ where $-\infty < \alpha \leq \beta <\infty$. For any $\epsilon > 0$ and any norm $||.||$ (since any norm is equivalent on an $n$-dimensional finite space), show that there exists a constant $M > 0$ such that the two inequalities hold:

(a) $||e^{At}|| \leq Me^{(\alpha - \epsilon)t}$ for every $t\leq 0$

(b) $||e^{At}|| \leq Me^{(\beta + \epsilon)t}$ for every $t\geq 0$

If all the real parts of eigenvalues are semisimple (i.e, geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ $=$ algebraitc multiplicity of $\lambda$), then we can choose $\epsilon = 0$ in part (a).

**My attempt:** I'm currently trying to modify the proof in Theorem 2.61 in Chicone's book (ODEs with applications), but I'm still stucked on modifying it successfully, as I couldn't use the two conditions $t\leq 0$ and real parts of its eigenvalues are contained in $[\alpha, \beta]$. For the semisimple part, I couldn't see where to start:P Can someone please help with this problem?

Comment: Please see here for the proof in Chicone's book on the closely related theorem to the two inequalities above: https://books.google.com/books?id=hyi88hKtqU4C&pg=PA4&hl=vi&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q=stability&f=false

Comment: Nobody could give me some help for either part of this problem?

Comment: What norm is on the LHS?

Comment: @user7530: Any norm:(

Comment: Have you considered the special case where A is diagonal and confirm your conjectures?

Comment: I tried to use Jordan Canonical Form for that case, but failed to achieve anything significantly:p Why you think it's wrong, John? Btw, it's not the conjecture though...It's a theorem without proof that my friend gave to me:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider the case where $A$ is made of a single Jordan block $J = \lambda I + B$, where $B$ is the nilpotent off-diagonal component of the block.

Now 
$$e^{Jt} = e^{\lambda It+Bt} = e^{\lambda t}e^{Bt} = e^{\lambda t}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{t^i}{i!}B^i.$$
Multiply and divide by $e^{\epsilon t}$ and take the norm to get
$$\|e^{Jt}\| = |e^{(\lambda+\epsilon)t}|\left\|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{t^i}{i!}B^ie^{-\epsilon t}\right\|.$$
Finally use the triangle inequality, and the fact that $e^{-x}f(x)$ is bounded on $x>0$ for any polynomial $f$.

I leave it to you to extend the above to the case of multiple Jordan blocks, and to massage these results into your specific inequalities.

Comment: thank you very much for your great hint! However, I currently have 2 questions for you:  1. How do you know that the norm $||B^i||$ is bounded for ANY norm even when $B$ is the nilpotent off-diagonal complement (I think we need to make it bounded by define the norm as $L_1$ or $L_\infty$, due to norm equivalence in this case)? 2. Is the matrix $A$ with multiple Jordan blocks $J_i$ ($i = 1, 2,\cdots, n$) can be expressed as $\sum_{i,k=1}^{n} \lambda_{ik}I+ B_{ij}$ where $B_ij$ is the nilpotent off-diagonal component of each block?

Comment: 1. $B^i$ just consists of 1s on the $i$th diagonal. So its norm can be computed explicitly rather easily, and is certainly bounded.
2. Not quite; instead of $I$ you have a matrix that looks like the identity in one block and is zero everywhere else.

Comment: Almost I'm not sure where your $k$ and $j$ indices came from.

Comment: I was fuzzy with the notation, but what I meant was that I expressed each block that looks like the identity but the off-diagonal contains 1s on the off-diagonal, as $\lambda_i I + B_i$. I don't see why it's not $I$ but "a matrix that looks like the identity in one block and is zero everywhere else." The expression $\lambda_i I + B_i$ describes exactly the matrix you just described.

Comment: can you try the last part of this problem as well (when all real parts of eigenvalues are semisimple)? I have stucked on that part for quite some time:P

Comment: Just diagonalize the matrix.

Comment: I realized that due to that condition, the matrix is always diagonalizable, so we can diagonalize the matrix. Now, the problem is essentially coming back to the general case with multiple blocks of Jordan matrix. Can you be clear on how to express $A$ as the linear combination of multiple $\lambda_i I + B_i$? I'm too dumb:p

Comment: Just decompose the matrix into blocks. If you need detailed help, consider posting a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my question is HOW to express that decomposition as linear combination of eigenvalues:P I posted the question here so that if you can, please give it a try:) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457361/representation-of-jordan-block-for-exponent-matrix